# implement wp-editor in a wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress

i create a new plugin .When the plugin is installed then a new link namely exam description setting will be come under the settings bar of  wordpress dashboard. It have a text field for exam name & text area for exam description. When i give the corresponding data then it will be saved in new db created by my plugin. Db structure is e_id(int),e_name(varchar),e_des(text).So now my need is to use **wp-editor** **instead of** using **text area** .Is there any method to implement it.?

Comment: Chek out this link http://www.presscoders.com/2011/11/how-to-reuse-the-post-editor-in-wordpress-3-3/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function **wp_editor** is your answer (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor).

`<?php
    wp_editor($e_des, 'editor_' . $e_id, array(
        'textarea_name' => 'editor_' . $e_id
    ));
?>`